# how to convert xlsx to csv in unix

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, export-to-csv, xlsx

I have a text file (`abc.txt`) which will be having the file name along with the path which is to be converted to `.csv`.

I am getting error saying that

> Selected exporter does not support saving multiple sheets in one file.

Only the current sheet will be saved. But it not getting saved for one tab as well.

Below is the query that I have wrote

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=date +'%d%m%Y'
Temp_Path=/my/first/path
cd $Temp_Path
#rm INBOUND_XLSX_FILES_.txt
find /my/second/path -name ".xlsx" >> "$Temp_Path/conversion.txt"
while IFS= read -r "f" ; do
    filename="${f%.*}"
    ssconvert "${filename}".xls
    "${filename}".csv
done < conversion.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

For a .xlsx with multiple sheets, you have to export each sheet as a separate .csv file. Of course different files must have different names.

You could either name the sheets by a number, using `%n`

```
ssconvert --export-file-per-sheet "$filename.xlsx" "$filename-%n.csv"
```

or name the sheets by their names, using `%s`

```
ssconvert --export-file-per-sheet "$filename.xlsx" "$filename-%s.csv"
```

Instead of `--export-file-per-sheet` you can also use the shorthand notation `-S` with exactly the same effect.

Comment: I tried the same, but i am getting error:  ssconvert --export-file-per-sheet "MomAndPop_Metadata_3-9-17_Approved.xlsx" "MomAndPop_Metadata_3-9-17_Approved.csv"
Reading file:///appinfprd/bi//IRP/IRPVendors/MomAndPop_Metadata_3-9-17_Approved.xlsx

** (ssconvert:19946): WARNING **: TODO

** (ssconvert:19946): CRITICAL **: wb_view_save_as: assertion `IS_WORKBOOK_VIEW (wbv)' failed

** (ssconvert:19946): CRITICAL **: wb_view_workbook: assertion `IS_WORKBOOK_VIEW (wbv)' failed

(ssconvert:19946): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your question. You still can (and in this case *should*) edit your question after posting it. Regarding the error: Even though I don't see a `%n` or `%s` in your command, the error message looks like there is a bug in `ssconvert`.